# Is this function O(N) or O(logn)? the for loop iterates through only half of the array but it checks both ends each time

Tags: c++, time, time-complexity

this is just an array and it traverses the array checking if the nums[i] is greater than both nums[i - 1] and nums[i+1]

```
for (int i = 1; i < nums.size() / 2; ++i) {
    if (nums[i] > nums[i - 1] && nums[i] > nums[i + 1]) {
        return i;
    }
    
    if (nums[nums.size() - i - 1] > nums[nums.size() - i] && 
        nums[nums.size() - i - 1] > nums[nums.size() - i - 2]) {
        return nums.size() - i - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's O(n). Think about it awhile more. Don't just consider iteration count (which is linear anyway O(cn) for constant c is cO(n), and thus still O(n), even when c is a constant fraction).

Comment: `O(1/2 N) == O(N)`.

Comment: The only reason it would be `O(log N)` is if your loop increment wasn't `++i`. Further, array accesses are constant-time operations, so there's effectively no change on the runtime complexity which, as others have stated, is `O(n)`.

Comment: Maybe think of it this way -- what if `nums.size()` was a million?  If the claim is `O(log n)`, then the number of times that loop should iterate would always be around a max of 20 times, regardless of the data being used.  Your loop doesn't come close to that claim of looping approx. 20 times.